# The name 'GridView1' does not exist in the current context Glossary.aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Glossary.aspx

Here is the html code for the site. I plan to add a login so people can edit the table based upon active directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title spellcheck="true">Lexis Nexis Glossary</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left: 720px">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TedGlossary" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Glsry_Taylor %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TermText], [DefNbr], [DefVerNbr], [DefText], [AmplifyingExplanationText], [SeeAlsoText], [AuthoritativeSrcText], [ScopeName], [DomnName], [GovernanceStateName], [LastUpdtTimestamp] FROM [Glossary] ORDER BY [TermText]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            " DataKeyNames="TermText,DefNbr,DefVerNbr" DataSourceID="TedGlossary" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TermText" HeaderText="Term" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TermText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefNbr" HeaderText="Definition #" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DefNbr" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefVerNbr" HeaderText="Definition Vers #" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DefVerNbr" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefText" HeaderText="Definition" SortExpression="DefText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AmplifyingExplanationText" HeaderText="Amplifying Explanation" SortExpression="AmplifyingExplanationText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SeeAlsoText" HeaderText="See Also" SortExpression="SeeAlsoText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AuthoritativeSrcText" HeaderText="Authoritative Source" SortExpression="AuthoritativeSrcText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ScopeName" HeaderText="Scope Name" SortExpression="ScopeName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DomnName" HeaderText="Domn Name" SortExpression="DomnName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GovernanceStateName" HeaderText="Governance State" SortExpression="GovernanceStateName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastUpdtTimestamp" HeaderText="Last Update" SortExpression="LastUpdtTimestamp" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').dataTable();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Glossary.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Home
{
    public partial class Glossary : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PreRender += new EventHandler(GridView1_PreRender);
        }
        protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
             //forces grid to render thead/th elements 
             GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true; 
             GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error of GridView 1 does not exist in its current context. I am not sure why that is happening. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: You are not referencing jQuery, and the datatables plugin for jQuery. This will not work even after you fix the Page declaration directive suggested by Darren on his answer.

Comment: @lcarus how do i reference the datatables plugin for jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing your page declaration at the top of your web form.

You should have something like this, to wire up the front and back ends. This basically tells the design view where the supporting class file is.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Glossary.aspx.cs" Inherits="Glossary" %>
```

if "may" need to be this one instead - as i see you have a namespace in your code-behind

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Glossary.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home.Glossary" %>
```

This would account for the error you're seeing as your .aspx.cs file doesn't know anything about the design view without that page directive.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, remove the extra double quote mark (") before the `DataKeyNames` attribute of the `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

This can by caused by GridView1 not being declared in the Glossary.aspx.designer.cs file. The file may need to first be created and/or the reference to GridView1 may need to be manually added.

Sample Glossary.aspx.designer.cs:

```
public partial class Glossary {
  protected global::Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView GridView1;
}
```